# activation link in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send activation link to registered user with the help of laravel. I have made some changes in `User.php` but

> "Declaration of User::setRememberToken() must be compatible with
>   Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::setRememberToken($value)"

this error is coming.
    my `User.php` is as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    //use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    protected $fillable =array('email','username','password','password_temp','code','active');

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');
    /**
     * get the identifier for user
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    /**
     * get the password for user
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    /**
     * get the email add where password is sent
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRemainderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getRememberToken(){}
    public function setRememberToken(){}
    public function getReminderEmail(){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for [setRememberToken](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Auth/UserInterface.html#method_setRememberToken), you can see that it has a signature of `void setRememberToken(string $value)`.  So, your code change

```
public function setRememberToken(){}
```

to

```
public function setRememberToken($value){}
```

Comment: ohh, thanks that error is gone now. Now its showing "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `username`, `password`, `code`, `active`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (arch.jovial@gmail.com, abcd, y$uyAUuyTtEpE7CvQ0GXjVh.pjfiQSb12DXqdzrVmlP1hJEPT2DlEZS, ypqZOqk1tPLUWjxDDk2IJhidwq1XHsorfsBLNeoACUnIZiaqXyJChjUvFPlY, 0, 2015-03-04 14:15:50, 2015-03-04 14:15:50))" in  C:\xampp\htdocs\newproject\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php this file. I am not geting what is this error??

Comment: It means you don't have a `updated_at` column in your `users` table in your database.

Comment: sorry that was silly mistake. now I am getting some more errors which I have to see thoroughly. Thank you !!